# WSMan PowerShell Provider?

Tags: .net, powershell

How come if you:

```
Get-PSProvider
```

You cant see a provider for WSMan, but you can:

```
Set-Location WSMan:\
```

Comment: I'm on powershell v3.0 and I can see wsman in the list of `get-psprovider`

Comment: im also on powershell 3, i havent enabled anything like psremoting though, have you ?

Comment: Yes. Psremoting is enabled here. Just do it with enable-psremoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell 3.0, WSMAN is a part of the Microsoft.WSMan.Management module which is not loaded by default. If you execute one of the Management module commands, PowerShell implicitly loads the module and the WSMAN drive is visible.

```
PS> Test-WSMan

wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0


PS> Get-PSProvider | ft name

Name
----
Alias
Environment
FileSystem
Function
Registry
Variable
WSMan
```

Alternatively you can explicitly load the Management module.

Comment: For me, It was winrm service which was not running, So I had to start it via  winrm config and then Test-WSMan worked.